# I am trying to add the same element to my list after every element that is already present in the list using the insert method

Tags: python, list, insert

```
mylist = ['.','.','.']
for i in mylist:
    mylist.insert(i,'x')


print(mylist)
```

The problem is that I keep on getting the error message:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I know of the join() method however I am trying to make it work so that the elements that i am adding can be manipulated later on.

Comment: best way is to just make a new list. It will be far clearer.

Comment: assuming you import the relevant itertools functions `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(repeat('.'), repeat('x', 3))))`.

Comment: @PaulRooney from that point of view, this would work too: `['.', 'x'] * 3`

Comment: Yeah that’s much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `for i in mylist` you get the actual list items in `i`, not their indexes. You then try to use `insert` - that functions requires an integer index (and is getting a string item instead). ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists))

In addition to that, you're iterating over a list while also changing it's length, that's a bad practice and a recipe for a lot of bugs.

The correct way would be to create a new list entirely:

```
mylist = ['.','.','.']
new_list = []
for item in mylist:
    new_list.append(item)
    new_list.append('x')
```

Your `new_list` is now: `['.', 'x', '.', 'x', '.', 'x']`

Comment: Worth adding: The two append()'s can be replaced by one [_extend_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists): `new_list.extend([item, 'x'])`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is insert takes an int and string as a parameter.

When you write...

```
for i in myList:
```

You are taking i as the value in each position. Since the values in myList are strings, that's the error message you are seeing. Try instead:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
```

This returns a list made up of the numbers starting from 0 and going to before len(myList). However, this **also** presents a problem. The list of positions is generated before the loop starts, so you have to be very careful since adding to the list doesn't change the number of interations. As such, the simplest implementation would be...

```
i = 1
while i < len(myList):
    myList.insert(i, 'x')
    i += 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.insert()` method works with indices not the element themselves. When you are saying `for i in mylist`, you are iterating over the elements, which are strings, so you get the error you mentioned, as indices can not be `str`. 
First line of thinking should be to go by indices, but then again, if you modify the list while iterating over it, you will modify the list everytime you insert an element and hence will get unexpected results. And it is highly discouraged. Nevertheless, if you want to do so, here you go:

```
mylist = ['.','.','.']
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist.insert(i+i+1,'x')

print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
['.', 'x', '.', 'x', '.', 'x']
```